# SDK 4.0 Facebook, no dialog to request permission publish_actions

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, scope

I created an app on facebook and via PHP SDK 4.0 I created the login and I need to have write permissions on the feed, but even we have added the permissions, when I do not log apparre the more window box to approve and grant permissions .

this is the code used:

```
<?php session_start(); 
require 'Facebook/autoload.php'; 




use Facebook\FacebookSession; 
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;



// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX' );

try {
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
// When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
// graph api request for user data
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
$response = $request->execute();
// get response
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

// print data
echo print_r( $graphObject, 1 );






if($session) {


try {


$response = (new FacebookRequest(
$session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
'link' => 'www.example.com',
'message' => 'User provided message'
)
))->execute()->getGraphObject();


echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');


} catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {


echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();


} 


}




} else {

$params = array(
scope => 'publish_actions'
//redirect_uri => $url
);
// show login url
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl($params) . '">Login</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: It will be nice if you could have just pasted the code snippet instead of the lengthy codes. That enables us to understand your code more effectively.

Comment: If you do already have a session from a previous successful login that did not include `publish_actions`, your code will not get to the point where it outputs the (new) login URL again … you should not only check if you have a valid user session, but also if you have the necessary permissions already – and if either one of that fails, you need to send the user through the login flow again. (And you should also take into account what the docs say about asking for permissions again that where already declined by the user once before.)

Comment: Hi @CBroe would you please share a link where to read about asking for declined permission again?

Comment: @MarcoGagliardi: That’s described here, in the section on how to manually build a login flow: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v1.0#reaskperms If you are using one of their SDKs, check its documentation as for how to re-ask for declined permissions.

Answer (score 0):

publish_actions should be approved by facebook for your application if you have already submitted for approval facebook might take upto a week till then you can't publish stories on facebook user's timeline.